# garer sur vs garer dans

Tags: prépositions

- J'ai garé la voiture dans/sur la rue
- J'ai garé la voiture dans/sur le parking.

Are the two prepositions correct in the 2 sentences? Is there a difference of meaning between both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any further context it's more usual to say:

> J'ai garé ma voiture dans la rue.

But you will find instances when you have to use *sur la rue*. Usually it is *sur* as opposed to something else. For instance if you live in a street where parking is possible either on the verge or on the road then it would be meaningful to say:

> J'ai garé ma voiture sur la rue.

We have an example [here](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/forum/affich-7139845-stationnement-sur-les-trottoirs) where both are used in the same paragraph, and it makes sense using a different preposition each time :

> ...si tout le monde se gare **dans la rue** des deux côtés, les voitures ne peuvent presque plus passer [...] si tout le monde (se) gare **sur la rue**, ce qui serait légal, la circulation sera très difficile.

In this example ***dans la rue*** refers to the road as a whole (road+pavement) whereas ***sur la rue*** refers to the part of the road usually used by cars.

Concerning car-parks it  depends on the type of car-park. If we park in an open car-park we'd usually say:

> J'ai garé la voiture sur le parking.

But if it's an indoor car-park we'd more likely say :

> J'ai garé la voiture dans le parking.

Answer (score 4):

Seul « sur la rue » ne se dit pas ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gar%C3%A9e+dans+la+rue%2Cgar%C3%A9e+sur+la+rue%2Cgar%C3%A9e+dans+le+parking%2Cgar%C3%A9e+sur+le+parking%2Cgar%C3%A9e+au+parking&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgar%C3%A9e%20dans%20la%20rue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgar%C3%A9e%20dans%20le%20parking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgar%C3%A9e%20sur%20le%20parking%3B%2Cc0)).

Il y a des gens qui utilisent « au parking », même si cette préposition n’apparaît pas dans les textes ([ngram](https://premium.courrier-picard.fr/id25695/article/2019-07-18/les-voitures-ametis-amiens-pourraient-se-garer-au-parking-perret)).

Il n'y a pas de différence sauf que les gens auront possiblement tendance à dire « sur le parking » lorsque celui-ci se trouve à ciel ouvert et « dans le parking » lorsqu'il s'agit d'un bâtiment.

Comment: « garé la voiture **au** parking » est [fréquent](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=gar%C3%A9+la+voiture+au+parking&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) et correct.